# XSD schema for multiple XML elements with at least one present, in any order

Tags: xml, xsd

This is my XML:

```
<animals>
  <cat/>
  <dog/>
  <cat/>
  <cat/>
</animals>
```

`<cat/>` and `<dog/>` elements can go in any order and there can be any number of them. But I do need to be sure that at least one `<cat/>` and at least one `<dog/>` is there. I can't understand how my XSD must look like.

This is what I tried:

```
<xs:complexType name="animals">
  <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="cat" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="dog" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

It doesn't show any errors when there are no `<cat/>`, for example.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19863952/xml-schema-maxoccurs-within-choice-element/19871075 . Generally, you can either use the `xs:all` group, or use a combination of `xs:sequence` and `xs:choice`, as shown in the answer of the link.

Comment: @Meyer I tried that, but still can't figure out what to do in my specific case. Can you post an XSD for my example, please?

Comment: can you use xsd 1.1?

Answer (score 1):

With XSD 1.1, it should be as simple as:

```
<xs:complexType name="animals">
  <xs:all>
    <xs:element name="cat" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="dog" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

With XSD 1.0, it gets a bit tricky.
However, we can observe that any valid
sequence of `<animals>` must either begin with a `<cat>` or a `<dog>` element.
The first element can possibly be repeated, but at one point,
there has to be the first instance of the other element.
So this gives a choice of two possible sequences.
After we have ensured that there is at least one `<cat>` and one `<dog>` element,
there can be any number of additional elements:

```
<xs:complexType name="animals">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:choice>
      <!-- At least one <cat> followed by one <dog> -->
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="cat" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="dog"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <!-- At least one <dog> followed by one <cat> -->
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="dog" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="cat"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:choice>
    <!-- Any remaining number of <cat> and <dog> -->
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="cat"/>
      <xs:element name="dog"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

For more complex element types, it is advisable to declare the elements once,
and then use `<xs:element ref="elementName"/>` in the complex type.

Comment: So what about cat, dog, cat, dog? For any sequence with more than 3 series of any one of the allowed elements it breaks down, doesn't it?